# How do I put javascript programmatically into <head> block?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

I need to put some javascript absolutely in the <head> block of the page -- it must execute before the rest of the page because a possible outcome of the script is to redirect to a different page.

However, when I use RegisterClientScriptInclude (to put some jQuery in there) and RegisterClientScriptBlock for my code which uses the jQuery, it puts it near the top of the <body> block, and it does not execute.  I can't see a way to programmatically put this javascript into the <head> block -- it must be programmatically because sometimes I don't want it there, and sometimes I do.

I've tried to see if I can directly reference Content1, the ID of the asp:Content element corresponding to the <head> block, but no go.

Just in case anyone thinks that RegisterStartupScript might work: it doesn't.  It puts it lower in the <body> block than everything else.  Oddly enough.

Want some code?  Here:

```
Type csType = this.GetType();
ClientScriptManager clientScript = Page.ClientScript;

if (!clientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(jqueryScriptName))
{
    clientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(jqueryScriptName, "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js");
}

if (!clientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(citrixDetectorScriptName))
{
    clientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, citrixDetectorScriptName, citrixDetectorScriptText, true);
}
```

By popular demand, how I detect the ActiveX component.  This is JScript.

```
try {
    var icaObj = new ActiveXObject("Citrix.ICAClient");

    var CitrixVersion = icaObj.ClientVersion.split(".");
    var MajorMinorVersion = CitrixVersion[0] + "." + CitrixVersion[1];
    if (MajorMinorVersion == "11.0") {
        // Citrix is OK
    }
    else {
        window.navigate("WrongCitrix.aspx?Citrix=" + MajorMinorVersion);
    }
}
catch (e) {

    window.navigate("NoCitrix.aspx");
}
```

If the ActiveX component is not present, then redirection is a page that tells the user they need to install it.  If the ActiveX component is any other version than 11.0, then the redirect is to a page that explains this and how to deal with the situation (backrevving for example).

An prior check during page load checks to make sure they have Internet Explorer v4 thru v9, because any other version will not work with the product (and IE10+ will crash if it even tries to load v11.0 of the ActiveX component).

Comment: Why wait until the page is rendered and use JavaScript to redirect? Save yourself a response and use `Server.Transfer` in the back-end.

Comment: and if user has script disabled???  makes no sense

Comment: I don't want to wait for the page to render, @codemonkeh, that's the issue! The javascript that goes into the head tries to detect whether a certain ActiveX component exists on the client's workstation.  If it does not, the user is redirected (via window.navigate) to another page which explains the problem and provides information on how to install the ActiveX component.  If the javascript is not in the head block, it doesn't execute even after the page is rendered.

Comment: @charlietfl, if the user has script disabled then they can't use the product that the page is the portal for.  It's that simple.  And this is a company intranet, not the public web.  Our way or the highway.  Sorry if that makes no sense to you, but it doesn't need to.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist my point was that by waiting to modify the JavaScript in the post-back you are rendering the page regardless (even if just the header). But I do see your point.

Comment: Can't you just do this entirely using `JavaScript`? How do you detect the ActiveX component?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this would be to dynamically add a meta refresh tag: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://whatever.example.com/'" />`

Comment: @Cyberherbalist why not just do it all on the client-side? Why do you need to post-back to insert JavaScript?

Comment: The ActiveX component will crash IE if it is IE version 10 or above.  Before the page even renders it checks for the browser version.  If it v4-9 then the page must use javascript to discover the ActiveX component and its version.  This IS done on the client side, and if the ActiveX component is not there or the wrong version then the javascript on the client side redirects to different pages.  If it is the correct component and version, then the page renders normally.  I don't know what else you can want me to do with it, @codemonkeh.

Comment: I understand. My point was that you appear to be dynamically inserting javascript from the back-end when all of the logic is in the front end. Why not just hard-code it in the actual head tag? Why insert it on post back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can insert PlaceHolder control wherever you want inside the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" 
   CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationTelerik.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
       "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('here'); </script>"));
}
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully.  Thanks, I had not know the PlaceHolder control could be used for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( newScriptNode );
```

or jQuery

```
$("head")[0].append( newScriptNode );
```

Comment: Those are neat, but I run into the same problem as before, because I can't know at design time whether or not I can add the script -- and adding the script conditionally at run time using the RegisterClientScriptBlock method puts the script in the Body, not the Head of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must insert JavaScript into the head tag, you can just make it an ASP.NET control and insert a control into it's child collection.

E.g. In the ASPX file:

```
<head runat="server" id="header">...</head>
```

In the code behind:

```
header.Controls.Add(new Literal("<script type='text/javascript'>...</script>"));
```

Although I do think you need to think about your process, it would be more efficient to redirect the user in the back-end before the page is rendered.

Oh and `RegisterStartupScript` correctly places your JavaScript after your html for increased load performance.

Comment: Before the page is rendered I don't know if they have the ActiveX component installed.  Until the javascript snippet I show above actually RUNS on the client, I don't know this.  Unless you know a way for IIS to mind-read the client before it sends any data to it?